# What is the meaning of using "days*24*60*60*1000" in cookie?

Tags: cookies

What is the meaning of using `days` * `24` * `60` * `60` * `1000` in a cookie?

I've seen it quite a lot and I don't understand what it means.

I need to create a function that reads the cookie and puts the value in a text box while uploading the page.

```
<body onload="readCookie()">
```

Answer (score 32):

Basically, 1000 is used here just for converting seconds to milliseconds.

Number of seconds in a day = 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400 seconds.

1 second = 1000 milliseconds.

So after calculating the expression, the result is in milliseconds.

days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = days * 86400000 ms

Comment: This was edited few minutes ago , so i just explain it for future reference.

Comment: * MOST days are 86400 sec, some are 82800, some are 90000, a few are 86401 and even fewer still are 86399 sec. Depending on your application it might be good to account for. A fun article explaining further can be found here:
https://swizec.com/blog/a-day-is-not-606024-seconds-long

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can be set with an “expiry date”, and that is given in milliseconds.

Days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 is therefore the milliseconds in a day – 1000 milliseconds * 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * days